# Get all text wrapped by THEN if condition

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

**html code**

```html
<div class=media>
   <div class=11></div>
   <div class=22></div>
   <div class=media-content>
       yes, this is the text<BR>
       that i want to compare below
       multiple line
    </div>
</div>

<div class=media>
   <div class=11></div>
   <div class=22></div>
   <div class=media-content>
       and i want to compare above text multiple line
       then if both same, i wanna break the loop
       But it is not work
    </div>
</div>
```

**Succeeded to select first element (was checked by chropath)**

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()]//div[@class="media-content"]')
```

**Succeeded to select second element (was checked by chropath)**

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()-1]//div[@class="media-content"]')
```

**But both text was NOT same but always TRUE then break.**

```py
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()]//div[@class="media-content"]').gettext() == driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()-1]//div[@class="media-content"]').gettext():
     break
```

Yes, it is not work.

I wanna compare the text(multi line) in both first and second `element(@class=media-content)`

If both multi-lined text was same, i wanna stop the loop.

But both text was NOT same as you see, but always become TRUE then STOPPED(break)

I am succeed to select item `(*with last[], last[]-1)`
But i don't why it works wrong.....

Is there anybody to troubleshoot my newbie code?
`//text()`, `.gettext()`, `.text()`

Comment: Can you please try `.text` instead of `.gettext()`

Comment: I try your advice, But it is not work.

Comment: Can you share the url you are attempting to scrape?

Comment: i editted my articles. and put the html.

Comment: Are these the only two media DIVs on the page? There may be a simpler way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
items1=[item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()-1]//div[@class="media-content"]')]
items2=[item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()]//div[@class="media-content"]')]
if items1==items2:
    print("pass")
else:
    print("fail")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I don't know what is different.. But finally, it works!!

Answer (score 0):

For me anser is (in case if where are more then one div[@class="media-content"] elements in singal div[@class="media"] node):

```
media_last = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()]//div[@class="media-content"]')
media_last = [a.gettext() for a in media_last]

media_not_last =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()-1]//div[@class="media-content"]')
media_not_last = [a.gettext() for a in media_not_last]

if media_last == media_not_last:
    break
```

you can't get method gettext at the array of elements

or if you want get jast a singl element use find_element_by_xpath method

Comment: sorry, it is not worked too. i editted my article and put the html code that you can verify.

Comment: Are you tryed to change find_elements_by_xpath to find_element_by_xpath?

And you can change gettext() to get_attribute("innerHTML")

Comment: I did it now, but not worked too.   (  elements >> element ) && ( a.gettext() >> a. get_attribute("innerHTML") )

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following using your html and I get the behaviour you expect:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'file:///<path to local html file>') # Used local html file for testing purposes
el1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()]//div[@class="media-content"]')
el2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="media"][last()-1]//div[@class="media-content"]')
if el1[0].text == el2[0].text:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

One thing to understand is that `driver.find_elements_by_path()` returns a `list` object. So even though it appears you are targeting specific elements in your page, they are stored in `list` objects and you should refer to them that way if you wish to access the text of the elements.